# How to change the greek symbol $\nu$ into upright bold

Tags: fonts, fontsize, font-encodings

How can I change the font of the Greek symbol `\nu` into upright bold?

Answer (score 5):

**The Idea**

Using the [`upgreek`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/was/upgreek.pdf) package gives you access to the upright Greek symbols. The [`bm`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/bm.pdf) package defines commands to access bold math symbols.

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} 

\begin{document}

Everyday $\nu$: $\nu$

Upright $\nu$: $\upnu$

Upright bold $\nu$ using the \verb@\mathbf@ command: $\mathbf{\upnu}$

Upright bold $\nu$ using the \texttt{bm} package: $\bm{\upnu}$

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution for `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{XITS Math} 
\begin{document}        
\Huge
$\nu\upnu\mitnu\mbfnu\mbfitnu
\mbfitsansnu\mbfsansnu $

\end{document}
```

[image]